# Does Apache ActiveMQ support Google protobuf as a transport protocol?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, protocol-buffers

I'm developing a messaging system and I used JBoss Netty + Google protobuf for the POC. protobuf was chosen for its swiftness of serialization/deserialization, relatively low traffic cost and availability in several languages.

Still, when it comes to production under heavy load a self-coded server application can never be as good as well-established and tested frameworks.

The problem is, I can't find such a framework that would allow me using protobuf as a transport protocol. Apache ActiveMQ and ActiveBlaze are the closest things I could find but the documentation is nearly absent.

I stumbled upon something that is [ActiveMQ protobuf](https://github.com/apache/activemq-protobuf) implementation but there is no reminding of it in official ActiveMQ documentation (its not among the supported protocols).

So my question is whether AMQ supports protobuf and if it does how it can be integrated?

Comment: @Tim, thanks for the answer!
It doesn't look like this is exactly what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, ActiveMQ uses its own OpenWire protocol or the Stomp protocol.  The protobuf bits are used for the underlying KahaDB Message store not the wire level portion.  You can store your protobuf data in a BytesMessage and transmit it that way to allow you to marshal and unmarshal the data on either end.